# Weird `NSRangeException` Crash

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Today, I tried to run my app, but it started crashing out of the blue. I didn't touch the code related to the place where the crash occurs.

Method where the crash occurs:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == usersTableView {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cell.basic.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
        print("users: \(users.count), row: \(indexPath.row)")
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(for: user.name, hidden: user.hidden)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell

    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Crash occurs on line:

```
let user = users[indexPath.row]
```

debugger output:

```
users: 2, row: 0
2017-03-05 15:05:57.771 MyAppName[22533:9069714] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Comment: Your `user` array contains only one object and you're trying to access the second element. How are you loading the users array or what's supposed to be in it?

Comment: how I posted, users array consists of 2 elements, and app crushes when tries to get the first one (index 0)

Comment: That's odd because the output doesn't match what's happening. `users.count` is `2` but the array is stored a as `SingleObjectArray` and crashes when trying to get the second object even though `indexPath.row` should be `0`. I'm at a loss, try cleaning and building again?

Comment: Yep, I have tried. I tried also removing derived data / removing app from simulator and nothing. I guess, it is xCode issue. And I will need to make cherry pick and revert to yesterdays commit.

Comment: how is `users` defined and initialised??

Comment: Have you set a debug breakpoint, and stepped through, using the console to evaluate all the objects?